# NSNotificationCenterのremoveObserverについて

Tags: swift, xcode

おはようございます。

iOSのMVCモデルを勉強しているときに、「Modelクラスへのオブサーバーをaddしたらremoveするものだ」というのを知りました。
そこで思ったのですが、同じobserverでもNSNotificationCenterを使ったアクティブ化、非アクティブ化の通知のとき（AppDelegate内に発信元を記載）には、removeObserverしているサンプル例をまだ見たことがありません。
これはそのようなサンプルが上がっていないだけで、実際はremoveするべきものなのでしょうか？それともそういう仕様なのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします

---

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("applicationWillResig‌​nActive", object: nil)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("applicationDidBecome‌​Active", object: nil)
}
```

という通知をつけています。

Comment: >同じobserverでもNSNotificationCenterを使ったアクティブ化、非アクティブ化の通知のとき（AppDelegate内に発信元を記載）
これは具体的には何を指していますか？メソッド名もしくは通知名があると分かり易いかも知れません。

Comment: pebble8888さん
ご返答ありがとうございます
メソッド名は`applicationWillResignActive`と`applicationDidBecomeActive`です。
それぞれに
`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("applicationWillResignActive", object: nil)`と
`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("applicationDidBecomeActive", object: nil)`
という通知をつけています。

Comment: 本題と関係ないですが、`UIApplication`のライフサイクルの通知は、`UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`や`UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`という文字列定数で投げられるので、あえて実装しなくてもよいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Foundation Release Notes for OS X v10.11 and iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html)より、

> In OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.0 NSNotificationCenter and NSDistributedNotificationCenter will no longer send notifications to registered observers that may be deallocated.
>   If the observer is able to be stored as a zeroing-weak reference the underlying storage will store the observer as a zeroing weak reference, alternatively if the object cannot be stored weakly (i.e. it has a custom retain/release mechanism that would prevent the runtime from being able to store the object weakly) it will store the object as a non-weak zeroing reference.

OSX v10.11 / iOS9 より、`NSNotificationCenter`は`addObserver()`で受け取ったオブザーバを`weak`で参照するように修正されたので、ARCで管理されているオブジェクトに通知したい場合には、明示的に`removeObserver()`を呼ぶ必要はなくなりました。

逆に言えば、iOS8以前をサポートするのであれば、`deinit()`などのタイミングで`removeObserver()`をコールする必要があります。

Comment: quesera2さん
ご返答ありがとうございます！

向こうで自動的にやってくれているのですね！
前のバージョンをサポートするかはわかりませんが、是非とも参考にさせていただきます。
ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

こちらに回答がありました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911651/in-arc-do-we-need-to-send-removeobserver-explicitly

Appleのドキュメントには必要だと書いてありますね。

> ```
> func addObserver(_ observer: AnyObject,
>         selector aSelector: Selector,
>             name aName: String?,
>           object anObject: AnyObject?)
> Be sure to invoke removeObserver:name:object: before notificationObserver or any object specified in
> ```
>
> addObserver:selector:name:object: is deallocated.

OSX 10.11以上ではremoveしなくても良くなったようです。

Comment: pebble8888さん
ご返答ありがとうございます！

バージョンによってやはり左右されるのですね........。
とりあえず書いておけば間違うことはないはずなので、書いておこうと思います！ありがとうございました！